# How to connect two values in while loop?

Tags: python

```py
print("Welcome to the CALCULATORBRO. Please type 'finish' when you have finished.")
CALCULATOR = []
number = ""
operator = ""
while number or operator != "finish":
    number = input("Please insert a number.")
    while number.isdigit() is False:
        number = input("Please insert a number")
        CALCULATOR.append(number)
        operator = input("Insert an operator.")
        OPERATORLIST = ["+", "-", "/", "*"]
        while operator not in OPERATORLIST:
            operator = input("Please insert an operator.")
            CALCULATOR.append(operator)
```

Hey there! I've been learning Python for 3-4 days and coded something like this3. My plan is taking the values from the list (CALCULATOR) and execute them as operations. However, I couldn't made the first while loop properly. How can I apply the while loop on both "operator" and "number" inputs?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `while number or operator != "finish":` to `while number != "finish" and operator != "finish":`.
`while number or operator != "finish":` first looks if `bool(number)` is `True` (this will be `True` when the string contains something), then looks if `operator` is unequal `"finish"`, and then looks if one of the results is True.

Comment: Thank you, I've fixed the mistake you mentioned. It works fine now!

Comment: @DenizKaya then accept my answer please !

Comment: @DenizKaya in case you dont know how : you have to click the grey checkmark on the left of the post !

Answer (score 1):

You can `break` the while loop inside the loop anytime user provides `finish`.

If you use `while number or operator != "finish":` there is a problem
Since you are using

```py
while number.isdigit() is False:
    number = (input("Please insert a number"))
```

Use can't provide `finish` by that user can't get out of the loop. The user has to give a digit mandatorily.

```py
print("Welcome to the CALCULATORBRO. Please type 'finish' when you have finished.")
CALCULATOR = []
number = ""
operator = ""
while True:
    number = input("Please insert a number 1: ")
    if (number == 'finish'): # break the loop and come out
        break
    while number.isdigit() is False:
        number = (input("Please insert a number2: "))
        if (number == 'finish'): # break the loop and come out
            break
    CALCULATOR.append(number)
    operator = input("Insert an operator.")
    if (operator == 'finish'):# break the loop and come out
        break
    OPERATORLIST = ["+", "-", "/", "*"]
    while operator not in OPERATORLIST:
        operator = input("Please insert an operator.")
        if (operator == 'finish'): # break the loop and come out
            break
    CALCULATOR.append(operator)
    number = input("Please insert a number 2: ")
    if (number == 'finish'):# break the loop and come out
        break
    while number.isdigit() is False:
        number = (input("Please insert a number 2: "))
        if (number == 'finish'): # break the loop and come out
            break
    CALCULATOR.append(number)
    print('result',eval("".join(CALCULATOR)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!